# I need delete cell after i tapped on alert action, but cells deleted before alert controller appear

Tags: ios, swift

I need delete cell after i tapped on alert action, but cells deleted before alert controller appear.

```
 @IBAction func binButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let subtitleString = NSAttributedString(string: "Are you sure to delete?", attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "SFProText-Regular", size: 13) ?? .systemFont(ofSize: 13),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ])
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Take Attention", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.setValue(subtitleString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
        alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AlertColor")
        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.white
        let cancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil)
        cancelAlert.setValue(UIColor(named: "Orange"), forKey: "titleTextColor")
        
        
        
        let actionDelete = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: nil)
        actionDelete.setValue(UIColor(named: "companyTextColor"), forKey: "titleTextColor")
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let selectedRows = usersTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            // 1
            var items = [String]()
            for indexPath in selectedRows  {
                items.append(userName[indexPath.row])
            }
            // 2
            for item in items {
                if let index = userName.firstIndex(of: item) {
                    userName.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
            // 3
            usersTableView.beginUpdates()
            usersTableView.deleteRows(at: selectedRows, with: .automatic)
            usersTableView.endUpdates()
        }
    
            alert.addAction(cancelAlert)
            alert.addAction(actionDelete)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

I need delete cell after i tapped on alert action, but cells deleted before alert controller appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the `handler` parameter of the action which is called when the user presses the button.

Most of your code is redundant, you can remove items at multiple indices from an array by removing the items backwards.

`usersTableView.begin/endUpdates()` has no effect for a single delete operation.

And the dismiss line is pointless as the alert controller dismisses the view implicitly when a button is pressed

```
let actionDelete = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in
    if let selectedRows = usersTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        for indexPath in selectedRows.reversed()  {
            userName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        usersTableView.deleteRows(at: selectedRows, with: .automatic)
    }

}
actionDelete.setValue(UIColor(named: "companyTextColor"), forKey: "titleTextColor")
```